# Conditional rendering in React not working after onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to conditionally show/hide a set of input fields based on a button click event. If the button was clicked, the value of `showExtraDetails` div will be toggled between `true` and `false`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
state = {
        ItemName: '',
        ItemPrice:'',
        ItemDate: '',
        ItemPlace: '',
        ItemType: '',
    }


/*On hitting submit button, I'm logging the state and resetting the form fields after the state was stored in to newArray after appending*/


handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    newArray = [...newArray, this.state];
    console.log(newArray)
    this.setState({
        ItemName: '',
        ItemPrice:'',
        ItemDate: '',
        ItemPlace: '',
        ItemType: '',
    })
}


/*When the input fields change, I'm updating the state*/

change =e =>{
    // this.props.onChange({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    })
}

/* toggling the showExtraDetails value after button was hit */

addExtraFoodDetails=() =>{
    // e.preventDefault()
    showExtraDetails = !showExtraDetails
    console.log(showExtraDetails)
    // e.preventDefault()
}


render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h5>Add Item</h5>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <input type="text" name="ItemName" placeholder="Enter the Item name" 
                    value={this.state.ItemName}
                    onChange={e=> this.change(e)}
                    />
                    <input type="number" name="ItemPrice" placeholder="Enter the item price" 
                        value={this.state.ItemPrice}
                        onChange={e=>this.change(e)}
                    />
                    <input type="date" name="ItemDate"
                        value={this.state.ItemDate}
                        onChange={e=>this.change(e)}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitItem" value="Save" />
                </form>
                <button onClick={this.addExtraDetails}>Add extra details</button>
                <br/>
                {showExtraDetails ? 
                (<div>
                    <input type="text" name="ItemPlace" value={this.state.ItemPlace}/>
                    <select name="ItemType" value={this.state.ItemType}>
                        <option value="none" disabled>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="type1">Type1</option>
                        <option value="type2">Type2</option>
                        <option value="type3">Type3</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
                </div>) : null
                }

                <br/>
                <ul>
                    {newArray.map(item => <li>{item.ItemName}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

But, when I hit the Add extra details button, I can only see the value of showExtraDetails as `true/false` after toggling, but the `div` is not getting updated with Showing/Hiding of the extra fields.

Am I missing something here? What is the best way to handle this? 
I've seen in angular `ngIf` would do this. But I don't see such equivalent in React. I got some suggestions to make use of CSS styles by toggling the id's of the div. But I'm trying to apply something which is React specific.

Thanks.

Comment: where is `showExtraDetails` defined? You need to put it in your state if you want react to rerender when that value changes (using `setState` not direct assignment)

Comment: @azium Thanks. This helps. But, as I mentioned in my question, is there any other way to get this done? Like as said, any specific react shortcut?

Comment: Putting things on state is precisely how this is done, it is the shortest cut

Comment: Okay. May be I should come out of angular way of directive for everything and think more in react's perspective, like state etc.

Answer (score 1):

In all probability, react is not re rendering. I suggest putting `showExtraDetails` in the state, and updating this state variable to cause a re render and thus cause your component to toggle correctly.